# Rails/Devise: valid_password? method returns nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-invitable

In my app there are two kinds of users (Athletes & Users). The Athlete model extends the User model and the regular user model assigns different roles to other kinds of users.

For some reason one some of my users with a certain kind of role, the `valid_password?` method  is not working. This is for users who have been invited via the `invitable` devise module. Any one else run into this? This is causing my app to not work properly where invited users cannot log in

Comment: Have they accepted the invitation? If they haven't accepted the invitation then they wouldn't have set their password yet.

Comment: @Hana - Thanks! That wind up being the issue

Answer (score 16):

This can be fixed by setting the `invitation_token` to `nil`.

Comment: I've been basing myself on this mistake for over 12 hours. Thank you very much.